# Resources for campaign based in Amn region

Tags: dnd-4e, published-adventures, forgotten-realms

I'm currently designing a campaign set in the Amn region of Faerun. I've got the Forgotten Realms Campaign guide from 4th edition and am using one of the old Living Forgotten Realms core quests ("Sense of Wonder") as a starting plot for my campaign to collect the characters from all over the world and bring them to the Amn region.

I'm looking for any background material that could help me design the campaign, maybe even possible adventures which are somehow related.

Adventures I've found so far:

1. Jungle Hunt (setting is in Chult, an Amnian trading post)
2. Sovereign of the Mines (set in the Amnian mining community Ioma town)
3. Crystal Clear (set in Athkatla)

Comment: Background information doesn't necessarily have to be confined to 4th edition, as long as you explicitly mention from which edition it is, I'm fine with it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most of 4e’s published (hardcopy) material was not *Forgotten Realms* and I don't think there are any specific 4e accessories for Amn. Fortunately for you, most of the 4e *Living Forgotten Realms* adventures are available for free online. While I don't know if there are any additional adventures based in Amn itself, as you noted there are a couple of Amnite colonies—Port Nyranzaru in Chult and Snowdown in the Moonshae Isles. Available *Living Forgotten Realms* adventures in the Moonshaes involving Amn and Amnian mercenaries are:

- *Nature’s Wrath* – Amnite pirates in the Moonshaes
- *Black Gold* – An Amnite agent in the Moonshaes
- *Black Blood* – A major encounter with Amnian mercenaries in the Moonshaes
- *Black Heart* – Adventure ties in with the Amnite agent from *Black Gold*

For more in-game historical background, there are the *Forgotten Realms Campaign Setting* and *Player’s Guide* for 3e, particularly the Shadow Thief of Amn Prestige Class in the latter.

In addition, AD&D 2e contains several *Forgotten Realms* accessories that directly deal with Amn, although these take place during the Time of Troubles in Faerûn before the Spellplague of 4e. Specifically,

- *Lands of Intrigue – Book Two:  Amn* (60+ pages)
- *Empires of the Sands* – The first 18 pages are dedicated to Amn
- *Volo’s Guide to the North* – Many references to Amn are interspersed throughout

You could also use material from *Baldur’s Gate 2: Shadows of Amn*, the computer game and the novel, which are centered in Amn and prominently feature Spellhold.

*Dragon* and *Dungeon* magazines have some Amn-related articles. For example, "Crimmor: City of Caravans" by Ed "I *am* Elminster!" Greenwood in *Dragon* #334 (pp. 22-34) is a loquacious, detailed treatment of the "Crossroads of Amn," including a keyed map, that was nominally for 3.5e but contains almost no mechanical information. (Courtesy of @HeyICanChan. Thanks!)

There are a couple of old 4e WotC forum threads on Amn. One, entitled "[Heroic Tier Adventure Ideas for Amn](http://community.wizards.com/forum/forgotten-realms/threads/1627336)," is self-explanatory and the other is "[Meldread's Amn](http://community.wizards.com/content/forum-topic/3076371)," one DM's detailed version of Amn about 100 years after the Spellplague, including maps.